# bluetooth to Bose speaker not working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, 22.04, speakers

I've just switched my Macbook Pro to Ubuntu thinking that would be a better OS, but I already hit a bug: the bluetooth to my Bose SoundLink Mobile speaker II is stuttering cranky and sounds like over saturated, I have tried a lot of different fixes I found over Internet but nothing helped me.
Here are the things I've tried:

- Installing blueman
- pacmd set-card-profile 3 a2dp_sink
- Writing `Enable=Source,Sink,Media,Socket` in `sudo nano /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf`
- `pactl set-port-latency-offset bluez_card.04_52_C7_10_4B_43 hifi-output 50000`
- `pactl set-port-latency-offset bluez_card.04_52_C7_10_4B_43 hifi-output 100000`
- `sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N"`
- `options snd-hda-intel model=generic`
- And of course `sudo service bluetooth restart` after every command above

[image]

[image]

Edit:
I have managed making it work (more or less decently by bringing the speaker just next to the computer, but as soon as it gets 2-3m aways it starts cranking again.

Comment: Depending on hardware, drivers could be a disadvantage in Linux compared to Mac, but I still prefer Linux overall. Have you looked for proprietary drivers for your hardware? (Wifi needs those for a Macbook anyway, but maybe bluetooth too in your case?)

Comment: @cipricus I tried installing drivers from https://github.com/leifliddy/macbook12-bluetooth-driver unfortunately it did not work either, I guess I will just accept having no bluetooth and use a jack ahah..

Comment: I wouldn't give up :)

Comment: @cipricus well the only option left I can think of is to deep dive into the bluetooth drivers and try to code/hack/fix it for my mac but like everyone of us I'm already multitasking between several other projects. Maybe one day!